# Set all RadTreeList items to edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radtreelist

I have been working with Telerik RadGrids and I haven't had any problem setting all items to edit mode when I'm populating the grid.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem)
    {
        e.Item.Edit = true;
    }
}
```

Now I'm working with a Telerik RadTreeList and I would like to do something similar. Is it any possible way to do this? As far as I have been searching, I haven't found any possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution goes as follows:

```
protected void RadTreeList1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (TreeListDataItem item in RadTreeList1.Items)
        {
            if (item is TreeListDataItem)
            {
                item.Edit = true;
            }
        }
        RadTreeList1.Rebind();
    }
}
```

The (!IsPostBack) condition would depend on if the TreeListDataItem get's populated at Page_Load.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check at http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treelist-server-side-basics.html?

`RadTreeList` has an `ItemCreated` event as well.

Can you try?

```
protected void RadTreeList1_ItemCreated(object sender, TreeListItemCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is TreeListDataItem)
    {
        TreeListDataItem item = e.Item as TreeListDataItem;
        item.Edit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, yes the RadTreeList has an ItemCreated event too but what I haven't been able to find is an "Edit" attribute which I could set to true. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, at the moment the ItemCreated event is getting fired and the item.Edit property is set to true. But I believe the problem here is that the property "IsInEditMode" is still set to false. So at this moment, the EditItemTemplate controls can't be found, just the ItemTemplates whose are the ones supposed to be shown at read only mode.

Comment: One thing that I can think of that the default edit mode of RadTreeList is EditForms. Take a look here and see if any of that applies to you. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treelist-edit-modes.html

Comment: I have configured "InPlace" for Edit Mode. With the RadGrid it worked well but  I'm having trouble with the RadTreeList.